# How to rename Serial connection with Teensyduino? Using Teensyduino for Serial reading

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port, teensy, com-port

I want to use a Teensyduino 3.2 for reading Serial input from my python program.
The python program uses the "serial.tools.list_ports" library to automatically detect Arduinos that are connected via USB with this simple code:

```
#____________finding Arduino COM Ports______________

ports = list(ser.comports())

for p in ports:
    print(p)
    if "Arduino" in p.description:
        x = str(p)
        arduinoCOM = x[:5]

        print("")
        print("____________________________")
        print("Arduino found! arduinoPort:")
        print(arduinoCOM)
        print("____________________________")
        print("")
```

Output of python program:

```
OM4 - USB Serial Device (COM4)
COM8 - Standard Serial over Bluetooth link (COM8)
COM51 - Arduino Uno (COM51)

____________________________
Arduino found! arduinoPort:
COM51
____________________________

COM7 - Standard Serial over Bluetooth link (COM7)
COM5 - USB Serial Device (COM5)
COM3 - Intel(R) Active Management Technology - SOL (COM3)
```

This works fine for any Arduino Boards because they're connection shows up as, for example: "Arduino Uno (COM51)" as shown in the Device Manager:
[Device Manager Snipping Tool.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mr5dW.png)

But the Teensy (blue Highlighted) only shows up as: "USB Serial Device (COM14)".
Like this, my python code cant differentiate any USB device from the Teensyduino.

How can i rename the connection with my Teensyduino to for example: "Teensyduino 3.2 (COM14)?

What i have already tried:

https://medium.com/@j0hnm4r5/changing-teensy-serial-name-and-port-name-2ca76552d26d
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nrT7WXFEEZI

Thank you very much in advance!

Kind regards Liamzgi

Comment: There is a related question on teensy's own forum: https://forum.pjrc.com/threads/25295-Automatically-find-a-Teensy-Board-with-Python-and-PySerial

Answer (score 0):

The `comports()` method returns a list of [`ListPortInfo`](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tools.html#serial.tools.list_ports.ListPortInfo) objects.

Instead of checking if the description contains the name 'Arduino', you can use the `vid` and `pid` members to see if those match those of the teensy bootloader (which you can copy from the properties you find in the windows device manager). The `ListPortInfo` also contains a number of other fields (such as a `manufacturer` field) which you can possibly use as well.